# Abandon session in ASP.NET MVC global.asax

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, forms-authentication, global-asax

I'm having a dilemma here. I've implemented an SSO Login through different ASP.Net MVC 5 projects and everything works just fine with Identity and Forms Authentication. But I have a requirement. If the user has never entered an app before he will not be logged in automatically, he has to click log in and subscribe to that app. So to an user who has never entered an app it must look just like an user who isn't logged in. I hope I'm clear with that.

I'm using a common machine key between apps and forms authentication to generate a ticket.

So, I make a validation in Global.asax in the method `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` and `Application_AcquireRequestState` to see if the current logged in user has previously subscribed to the app, if he has, nothing happens, he enters as a logged in user normally. But if he hasn't subscribed it must abandon the session.

I've tried using the `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` but this one destroys the cookie and removes the sso aspect of it. And `Session.Abandon()` is doing nothing. So, my question is how to abandon the session or the current formsauthentication without deleting cookies so if he visits any other app he's subscribed to he won't have any problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing it, I had to change the name of the FormsAuthentication Cookie and validate if it existed with the other name every time I want to add my custom validation, and then use FormsAuthentication.signOut() and asigning the Current.User a generic empty user.